# HTTP load request is not working in iOS12

Tags: ios, swift, ios12

I having an application which open the direction between two location in a webview using "http://maps.google.com" URL. but it is not working in iOS12. And also enabled the exceptional domain in App transport security plist value. Even though it is not working.

Comment: Show us some code. What happens? Do you get an error message?

Comment: update device, now ios12 is released

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me, the issue was caused by server trust check from the WKWebView.

To fix this I had to handle the challenge authentication callback and return a server trust credential.

Swift 4

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, 
    didReceive challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge, 
    completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Void) 
{
    if(challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod == NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust)
    {
        let cred = URLCredential(trust: challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust!)
        completionHandler(.useCredential, cred)
    }
    else
    {
        completionHandler(.performDefaultHandling, nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please update your iOS 12 as the **latest** version asap.

`iOS 12 beta` version has an issue of CORS with **wkwebview**.

[Refer to this link.](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/108318)

And it has been fixed now.